# PRESTASHOP This product must be in the default category

Tags: php, prestashop

Como se debe carga la categoría por defecto en Prestashop al importar productos por medio de ajax o de una API, con el objetivo que no salga un error cuando se va a editar el producto en el BO de PS 1.7

Estoy tratando de actualizar los productos desde una fuente externa y asignarlos a una categoría, según las tablas de la base de datos se ejecuta correctamente, pero en el árbol de categorías en cada producto la categoría que estoy agregando no aparece seleccionada y no aparece disponible por defecto

```
$product = new Product($id_product);
$product->id_tax_rules_group = 1;
$product->id_category_default = $cats[0]; //primera categoría del array
$product->id_category = $cats; //listado de categorías  
$product->save();

$product->addToCategories($cats1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$product->id_category_default = $cats[0];
```

Esta asignación está mal, a no ser que muestres el código de obtención de $cats.

```
$product->id_category_default deber ser igual a un entero que corresponde al id_category de la categoría que quieras asignar.

Otro error también lo tienes en $product->id_category = $cats;
```

Mira este enlace donde el compañero lo resuelve muy bien:

[Add category when I create a product on PrestaShop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41146285)